# Execute commands for the google assistant - Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-assistant-sdk

I am looking forward to a node package that allows you to run commands to get the same output we get in the google assistant on our android phones. The command which we say after saying 'Ok Google' or 'Hey Google' to execute to give the same output. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a popular NPM package:

> "The Google Assistant SDK - A version in node to play around with! I've abstracted it from needing to use the mic and speakers on the device running the code (but it still can!) so that you can pass audio in and play audio back however you want to."
>
> https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-assistant

Here is the client library from Google:

> "The Actions on Google Node.js client library is the recommended way for accessing and interacting with the Actions on Google platform if you are creating a fulfillment webhook in JavaScript.
>
> https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs

and its corresponding documentation:

> https://developers.google.com/assistant/actions/reference/nodejsv2/overview

Comment: Thanks a lot.   .